# Mapping First Order logic Expression to Database Entry (Extracting information from a FOL expression)

Tags: nlp, nltk, context-free-grammar, first-order-logic

I am building a **question answering** system restricted to medical queries. I am using first order logic(FOL) to represent questions asked. I have managed to arrive at a FOL expression employing the procedures outlined by the [**NLTK BOOK**](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch10.html#sec-evaluating-english-sentences).

For example, for a question like:

> What are the symptoms of diabetes?

,I have arrived at a representation that looks like:

> WHQ(list,exists y.(symptoms(y) & refersTo(y,diabetes)))

Here, **WHQ** denotes that the question is a What question;**list** denotes that the outpust must be some sort of list of values;**y** is some value(variable) that maps to **symptoms**.

My question is,

1. Is this approach(or representation) valid?
2. Considering that the FOL expression is valid, how would i "programmaticaly" map this FOL expression to retrieve the **answer** from a database?

Any additional insights would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [paper](http://dlsu.academia.edu/KenstonChoi/Papers/1558781/A_Question_Answering_System_that_Performs_Evaluations_and_Comparisons_on_Structured_Data_for_Business_Intelligence_in_Biotechnology) (co-authored) that discusses the same issue. The representation is DRS which is related to FOL. The representation is then transformed to SQL. Some predicates have to be represented as well. While the paper focuses on comparisons and evaluations, factoid questions are covered as well.